# vispy set the line width of the mesh in a scene.sphere?

Tags: python, opengl, vispy

How do you set the line width of the mesh of a vispy.scene.visuals.Sphere?

If I add a `vispy.scene.Line` with a `width`, it affects the mesh of the previously added sphere as well.

Somehow there seems to be a missing call to `vispy.gloo.set_line_width` in the pipeline or something.

Comment: Update: I posted an issue for this: https://github.com/vispy/vispy/issues/1240

Comment: Following your bugreport, I believe the only way now to set line width is globally via `vispy.gloo.wrappers.set_line_width(width=8.0)`. Is it correct?